# Line break (continuation) for commands (options, arguments)

Tags: macros, line-breaking, optional-arguments, options

How to do proper line breaking (continuation) for commands, i.e. their options and/or their arguments? For example, in order to transform this:

```
\usepackage[top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=1.0cm, right=1.0cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
```

Into this:

```
\usepackage[top=1.0cm, 
            bottom=1.0cm,
            left=1.0cm,
            right=1.0cm,
            includehead,
            includefoot]{geometry}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The form of the input is mostly your responsibility. Remember that an end of line count as a space, but a blank line counts as and end of paragraph command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question. Do you want to break lines automatically? You can just type RETURN. Also, insert a comment command at the end of line.

```
\usepackage[top=1.0cm,%
            bottom=1.0cm,%
            left=1.0cm,%
            right=1.0cm,%
            includehead,%
            includefoot]{geometry}
```

Comment: Do I really need `%` at the end? Just tested - it seems to compile without it.

Comment: For option lists the `%` at the end of lines is not necessary. However it is in many other situations, particularly in definitions of commands.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the quick turn guys. Best regards.

Answer (score 6):

`keyval` (and I think most key/value parsing packages following it) trims all white space around the `,` and the `=`. So

```
[a=b,c=d]
```

is the same as

```
[ a
=
b , , , ,
c
=
d
]
```

Comment: That's good news. Basically, I asked this question because I was afraid that LaTeX is being very precise on how one types commands. But, now it seems that parser does a great job on grabbing those tokens. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Haroogan, yes. This is a good property. We don't need to format our texts and remove all the extra empty spaces between the words (as we have in MS Word).

Comment: Just a very kind author of that package, takes care of user input.